# Robot framework operating system - which keyword to append current date time stamp to all files’ name

Tags: robotframework

I am learning robot framework `operating system` library.

I want to do following steps:

1. copy file from original folder to test folder which I knew how to do it by using `Copy Files`.
2. Get current date time stamp and stored as variable
3. Append the date time stamp to all files’ name in test folder, I am not sure which keyword to use. Please advise.

Final files :

```
Testfile1-19112021175630.txt
Testfile2-19112021175630.txt
Testfile3-19112021175630.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [DateTime](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html) library.

Better to use it before copying the files, because you can prepare the destination filename with the timestamp.

```
Pseudo-code:
    Loop for all files:
        name= Get Filename
        date= Get Current DateTime
        new_name= name + date (or Replace name ('.ext', '${date}.ext')
        Copy name new_name
```

Comment: I mentioned that i know. What i am asking is point 3, which keyword is suitable?

Comment: You have to look the available keywords and decide which ones to use. Consider also the `String` library.